# What makes us not to go for a spelling reform for the English Language?

Tags: orthography, learning

English alphabet is inadequate for its sounds. This makes us to make spelling mistakes and miscommunication. Why the world is not favoring spelling reform that will help us to use the English language with ease and the second language learners to learn it easily and quickly.

Comment: Did you know that the silent _g_ in [_benign_](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=benign&allowed_in_frame=0) is the same as the pronounced one in [_malignant_](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=malign&allowed_in_frame=0)?

Comment: If you want to have spelling reform, you have to get everyone to agree to it. It's that simple. Can you figure out how to do that?

Comment: So why don't you lobby the *International English Standards Authority* to do this?  (Oh, wait!  There is no *International English Standards Authority*.)

Answer (score 1):

Spelling mistakes for whom? It's true that the English language is not phonetic. so what? very few other languages are either.